# Executar um método quando o Webservice for Iniciado

Tags: c#, web-service

Tenho um Webservice que está funcionando normalmente. Neste momento surgiu a necessidade de executar um método que se chama "RecuperarAposFalha" que precisa ser executado assim que o Webservice for iniciado. Este é um método para subir alguns dados do banco de dados quando o Webservice voltar de alguma falha, como queda de energia, reboot acidental, etc. Como posso fazer isso sem precisar consumir esse método em uma outra aplicação ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faça seu método estático em uma classe em separado. Por exemplo:

```
public static class Inicializacao 
{
    public void RecuperarAposFalha() 
    {
        /* Coloque aqui os passos para recuperação. */
    }
}
```

Chame o método em `Application_Start` do arquivo `Global.asax`:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Inicializacao.RecuperarAposFalha();
        ...
    }
```